# Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to byte using ternary operator

Tags: java, byte

Working on a project utilizing byte array manipulation, I have attempted to write something like this:

```
boolean enabled = getEnabled();

byte enabledByte = enabled ? 0x01 : 0x00; // compile error
```

The issue that I am facing, is that the above will not compile.

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to byte

However if I expand this to the following, it works without issue:

```
boolean enabled = getEnabled();

byte enabledByte;
if (enabled) {

    enabledByte = 0x01;
} else {

    enabledByte = 0x00;
}
```

Leading me to the question

> Why can I not use byte assignments in short if statements?

Comment: Additionally interesting: why does `byte enabledByte = true ? 0x01 : 0x00;` compile?

Comment: @ldz It's because `true ? 0x01 : 0x00` is a constant expression, unlike the case when a variable is used instead of the `true` literal. See my answer for how the language spec dictates this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`0x00` and `0x01` are *`int`* literals: they are expressions with `int` type. An `int` can't usually be assigned to a `byte`, but it *can* if the expression is compile-time constant, provided the value is in the range of `byte`.

With the conditional, the assigned value is compile-time constant:

```
if (enabled) {
  enabledByte = 0x01;
} else {
  enabledByte = 0x00;
}
```

These assignments are completely separate from the compiler's point of view. There is one statement which assigns the constant value 1, and one statement which assigns the constant value 0.

For each statement, the compiler can guarantee that fits into the range of byte, so it automatically narrows the assigned value to byte.

However, the assignment with the conditional operator:

```
enabledByte = enabled ? 0x01 : 0x00;
```

The rhs expression is of type `int`, but *isn't* compile time constant, because `enabled` isn't known at compile time. It doesn't matter that the two possible values *are* compile-time constant, and both would fit into a `byte`: the non-constant first operand makes it non-constant.  As such, the result of the conditional operator expression cannot be automatically narrowed.

The most efficient solution to this is to cast the second and third operands to `byte`:

```
enabled ? (byte) 0x01 : (byte) 0x00
```

This is better than

```
(byte) (enabled ? 0x01 : 0x00)
```

Because the latter will cast at runtime, each time the expression is evaluated, whereas the former does not: the operands are already bytes at compile-time, so no cast is necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Number literals are naturally of type `int`, not `byte`.

The language has a special implicit conversion from numeric *literals* (< 128) to `byte`, so your second example doesn't need a cast.

However, wrapping the literals in a conditional operator creates an expression of type `int` that isn't a literal, so you need the cast.

Answer (score 0):

You need at least one cast to flip the ternary expression to a `byte`, it's defaulting to an `int` because of the ternary.

```
byte enabledByte = enabled ? (byte) 0x01 : 0x00;
```

It works the same way if you use decimal literals

```
byte enabledByte = enabled ? (byte) 1 : 0;
```

See also [JLS-15.25.2 - Numeric Conditional Expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25.2) which says (in part)

> Otherwise, binary numeric promotion ([§5.6.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2)) is applied to the operand types, and the type of the conditional expression is the promoted type of the second and third operands.

Answer (score 0):

The rule governing the narrowing conversion from `int` to `byte` is specified in the language specification, section on [assignment contexts](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2) (emphasis on constant expression):

> In addition, **if the expression is a constant expression** (§15.28) of type `byte`, `short`, `char`, or `int`:
>
> - A narrowing primitive conversion may be used if the type of the variable is `byte`, `short`, or `char`, and the value of the constant expression is representable in the type of the variable.
>
> ...
>
> If the type of the expression cannot be converted to the type of the variable by a conversion permitted in an assignment context, then a compile-time error occurs.

The ternary conditional expression `enabled ? 0x01 : 0x00` is not a [constant expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28), unlike the integer literals. Therefore, it cannot be implicitly converted using narrowing conversion.

Note that you can solve the error by casting one of the operands of the conditional expression:

```
byte enabledByte = enabled ? (byte) 0x01 : 0x00;
```