# Java type mismatch cannot convert from int to byte?

Tags: java, casting, type-conversion

I'm wondering why the `//1` statements are accepted by the compiler and the `//2` statements are not

```
    //1
    int k = 99999999;
    byte l = (byte)k;

    //2
    byte b = 1;
    int i = 10;
    byte z = (byte)i+b; //compiler rejected
```

[Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to byte using ternary operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42890653/type-mismatch-cannot-convert-from-int-to-byte-using-ternary-operator) gave me somewhat of an idea but I don't understand why the compiler can resolve the variable `l` in `//1` as acceptable and not `i` in `//2`

Comment: Operator/casting precedence. If you write `(byte)(i+b)` it will work. Otherwise the end result is an `int`.

Comment: Thanks it seems that this https://stackoverflow.com/a/9816020/4777993 is the answer, I will now look up how this applies to other types.

Answer (score 1):

You cast to `byte` just the first number `i` and not the whole sum. You have to add the brackets:

```
byte z = (byte) (i+b);
```

Comment: but the `b` is already a byte?

Comment: `int` + `byte` will be `int`.

Answer (score 1):

Plus always returns int. So you need to explicitly typecast whole expression to byte.

```
(byte)(i+b)
```

Comment: "plus always returns an int" except when it returns a long, float, double or String.

Comment: Agree... I meant it for byte.